# git clone from Visual studio (using the Git Source Control Provider)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I am using Git Source Control Provider version 1.1 with Visual Studio 2012.

Is it possible to perform a clone operation from within the Visual Studio interface?

i.e Is there an equivalent of the 'git clone' command while using the Git Source Control Provider for Visual Studio?

Thanks.

-Anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were unable to clone because the 'Git' menu was not showing up in Visual Studio 2012. The Git menu was made available in the VS interface by following the steps below:

Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Add-in Security and then add the path to the VS Addins (in our case: C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins) and then restart VS 2012

Note: The files GitPlugin.AddIn and GitPlugin.dll should be available in the Addins folder of VS.

Once VS 2012 is restarted, the Git menu will be available. The Git menu provides an option to clone the repository.

Hope this helps :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/discussions/402610), it seems like the Git Source Control Provider does not support cloning through the GUI yet. Try cloning from the git bash command line with `git clone REPO_URL`.